# Delete Answer cast undelete vote if answer is already deleted

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

While reviewing flags in the 10k tools, you sometimes see a "Delete Answer" or "Delete Question" button next to the "Flag or disagree..." button.

Normally if you click the button, you cast a delete vote. But if the post already has 3 votes and is deleted, you can still click the button, but it then cast an undelete vote.  And this is probably not the requested action.

So I think it should be better to ignore extra delete votes, because there are other channels to cast undelete votes.

Comment: +1 just happened to me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428552/user-profile-application-proxy-failed-to-retrieve-partitions-from-user-profile-a/14118490#14118490

Comment: This drives me crazy.  It does not update into the deleted state, so you vote again and reverse yourself. A vote to delete should **NEVER** silently convert to a vote to undelete. It's a gnarly old bug.

Answer (score 2):

Flags are no longer shown in the 10k tools -- problem solved. :-)

The 10k tools include a page for deletions and undeletions, but the page is just a list of links.  If you want to actually cast votes, you have to click through to the post, where you'll see live updates if the deletion status changes.